# Newlookuprow not return 2 Informatica

Tags: dynamic, lookup, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a problem with the dynamic lookup of the Informatica. My new lookup row is only returning 0 (duplicate) and 1 (Insert) it never returns 2(update). When i added a new row with the same natural key and update a column in a row the lookup returns 1 rather 2 which is update!

Comment: Can you please add some details? One quick thought I have is that length  of one of the ports is not enough, e.g. if you use string(5) to compare 'abcdefg' would result in 'abcdefg' != 'abcde' thus returning a NewLookupRow as 1.

Comment: hello i tried what you said but still i have the same problem! Do i have to check all the ports of lookup up table? I have a look up table with 5 ports and i compare only the 3  of them.

Comment: now is working but i have another problem. Lets say i add another row with the same key but i update the description to my table. It shows number 2 correctly but it shows the old row with number two rather 0 which is duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) of things to look for:

1. Check in the property label of the lookup transformation that the
   "Insert Else Updated" and "Update else insert" are checked (they are
   not by default).
2. Check also the port that could cause an update are correctly associated (in the port label) and have not the "Ignore in comparison" flag checked.

Comment: the label property is checked. Now the ignore in comparison flag is checked and i can not unchecked it. it doesnt let me!

Comment: now is working but i have another problem. Lets say i add another row with the same key but i update the description to my table. It shows number 2 correctly but it shows the old row with number two rather 0 which is duplicate.

Comment: The comparison should be on the business key. Try to read this tutorial: http://www.dwbiconcepts.com/etl/14-etl-informatica/16-dynamic-lookup-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved it! The problem is that you need to sort your table ports before creating the dynamic lookup!

Comment: Are you sure that was this that solved your problem? The port order should not have any effect.